# SRDF and group_state

Tags: ros, srdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I'm trying to start up in Gazebo my arm manipulator with a fixed configuration. In order to, I have created an SRDF file, with a group for the arm, and a group_state with the homing position. However I don't know how to active this homing position. Could anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Ane

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172658/srdf-and-group_state/) by [Ane](https://answers.ros.org/users/684/ane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your project involves creating a 3D model file to realize your robot on Gazebo, you should better use the model format [SDF](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=build_robot) that Gazebo works the best with.

I doubt if Gazebo works with [SRDF](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/62/sdf-vs-urdf-what-should-one-use/), which was invented to [compensate semantic context of a robot in URDF format](http://wiki.ros.org/srdf/review#Intent).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0